# Mersenne number variant

Tags: number-theory, mersenne-numbers

It appears that all numbers of the form $(6^p-1)/5$ for prime $p$ are square free and are coprime to each other. Is this true?

This seems like it might be related to Mersenne numbers, except with 6 instead of 2.  For example, these numbers are prime for $p\in\{2,5,29,71,...\}$. Though I don't know if that is helpful here.

Comment: Well, $\gcd(6^a-1,6^b-1)=6^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$, so they are indeed coprime.

Comment: Nobody currently knows any simply formula that always produces squarefree numbers, so $(6^p-1)/5$ is unlikely to always be squarefree either. This would imply that the order of $6$ modulo $q^2$ can never be a prime (for primes $q>5$). While such prime orders are certainly going to be rare, probabilistically they should occur sporadically.

Comment: As to being square free, well the analogous claim is conjectured for Mersenne primes, but has not been shown.  As in that case, it's not hard to show that if $p^2\,|\,(6^q-1)$ then $6^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$, so an analog of the Wieferich primes.  A quick search found no such primes, but I didn't go out that far.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Asaelr, you've proved the second half, and Greg Martin and Lulu, you've convinced me the first half is a difficult open question.  I consider this now answered.  Thanks!

Comment: @GregMartin I think , you mean formulas of this kind , since there are simple formulas always producing squarefree numbers ,  for example $n$# or even $p_n$. For generalized Mersenne or generalized Fermat numbers , I guess no formula is KNOWN to produce always squarefree numbers. For Mersenne numbers with prime index and Fermat numbers there is however a very high probability that they are all squarefree.